# Como atualizo uma página em um horário definido?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Preciso atualizar uma página a cada 15min, porém com um horário definido (HH:00 | HH:15 | HH:30 | HH:45).

Tentei fazer isso...

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var data = new Date();
                var minute = data.getMinutes();
                if(minute == 15 || minute == 30 || minute == 45 || minute == 0){
                    location.href = "NewFile.jsp";
                }
            }, 3000);
        });

    </script>
```

O setTimeout só faz o ciclo uma vez?

Comment: O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Estou editando.

Comment: Não sei quem tinha comentado aqui ""Troque por setInterval", funcionou! Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `setTimeout` só é executado 1 vez. Se quer que seja ininterrupto, troque por `setInterval`.

Agora surge um problema: como o ciclo é rodado a cada 3 segundos, irá dar reload na página a cada 3 segundos quando o minuto atender a uma das condições do `if`. O que você pode fazer é criar um localStorage para guardar o valor do minuto para que o reload só ocorra 1 vez, e colocando mais uma condição no `if` verificando se o localStorage é diferente do minuto atual, e incluir as condições `||` dentro de parênteses `()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Handler for .ready() called.
   window.setInterval(function () {
       var data = new Date();
       var minute = data.getMinutes();
       if((minute == 15 || minute == 20 || minute == 45 || minute == 0) && localStorage.getItem("reload") != minute){
          localStorage.setItem("reload", minute);
          setTimeout(function(){
             location.href = "teste.html";
          }, 500);
       }
   }, 3000);
});
```

> Veja que usei um setTimeout antes de recarregar a página para que não
>   haja problemas em criar o localStorage (embora já vi comentários de
>   que o localStorage seja síncrono, mas não tenho certeza e não achei documentação a respeito).

Comment: Beleza! Obrigado pela resposta! vou testar e ja retorno!

Comment: a Primeira vez que ele atualiza, atualiza apenas uma vez, como falou, porém, quando ele atualiza a segunda vez, ele atualiza varias vezes, acho que o valor do localStorage não está atualizando., ficando sempre diferente

Comment: Pronto. Faltou incluir as condições `||` entre parênteses.

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado Sam!

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema usando setInterval, ao invés de setTimeout.

Ficou assim:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            window.setInterval(function () {
                var data = new Date();
                var n = data.getSeconds();
                var minute = data.getMinutes();

                if(minute == 15 || minute == 20 || minute == 45 || minute == 0){
                    if(n < 6){
                        location.href = "NewFile.jsp";
                    }
                }
            }, 3000);
        });

</script>
```